# Isolating year in Python when given data in form MM/DD/YY

Tags: python, date

I have data with three columns `[Date|Name|Comment]` ranging from 2018 to 2014 and I want to isolate the entries that were made in 2017.

I'm using the datascience library (documentation: http://data8.org/datascience/index.html) and I've been able to sort it simply just by applying

```
.sort('Date received', descending = True)
```

but when I want to apply any kind of comparison like

```
.where('Date received', are.above('1/1/2016'))
```

the boolean is only applied to the last input, meaning I'm getting output that looks like:

```
[1/1/2017, '', '']

[1/1/2017, '', '']

[1/1/2018, '', '']

...
```

rather than:

```
[1/2/2016, '', '']

[1/2/2016, '', '']

[1/3/2016, '', '']

...
```

which is what i'd hoped for.

In the same way, applying:

```
.where('Date received', are.above('1/1'))
```

makes it select only by day with no regard for year or month,

applying:

```
.where('Date received', are.above('1'))
```

makes it select only by month with no regard for year or day.

But for some reason when I apply

```
.where('Date received', are.equal_to('1/1/2017'))
```

I get only the comments made on January 1st, 2017.

The fact that I'm able to sort it with sort() tells me that I should be able to search just by year, but I read through all the documentation for Tables and I haven't been able to find any information on that.

I've been looking at the datetime library and this code seemed like it could help:

```
import datetime
def date_key(a):
    a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    return a

sorted_dates = sorted(sorted_dates, key=date_key)
```

If I could just pop out the %Y value and use:

```
.where(Year, are.equal_to(16))
```

That would be all I need but I've trawled through the internet and couldn't find (or understand) anything on that.

Full Code:

```
import numpy as np

from datascience import *

comp = Table.read_table('Comments.csv')

comp = comp.sort('Date received', descending = True)
```

This gives me the data sorted perfectly by date.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I have understood well. Are you asking how to filter dates in Python?

Comment: do you need to use `datascience` library for this?

Comment: I would be open to using other libraries as well to solve this. And yes, I'm trying to pick out tuples by the year they were entered. The issue is that the year they were entered is in a string in format 'MM/DD/YY'

Answer (score 0):

Your date column is in string format. I suggest you convert it to int or datetime format to sort it correctly :

```
import datetime
from datascience import Table
#create a table with one column of dates for example
t = Table().with_columns("date", ["1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/1/2016", "1/1/2018", "1/2/2016"])

#add a new column called datetime with date in datetime format : 
t.append_column("datetime", [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y') for d in t["date"]])

#sort the table on datetime column
In [13]: t.sort("datetime", descending=False)
Out[13]: 
date     | datetime
1/1/2016 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
1/2/2016 | 2016-02-01 00:00:00
1/1/2017 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1/2/2017 | 2017-02-01 00:00:00
1/1/2018 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

If you are interested in the year create a column `year`:

```
t.append_column("year", [d.year for d in t["datetime"]])
```

then keep only 2017 :

```
In [17]: from datascience import  are

In [18]: t.where("year", are.equal_to(2017))
Out[18]: 
date     | datetime            | year
1/1/2017 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 2017
1/2/2017 | 2017-02-01 00:00:00 | 2017
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! To clarify, once I convert entries into datetime format, I can pick out individual values with lines like .day .month .year?

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to leverage `datetime` for isolating dates in a range of 2 dates. For example:

```
import datetime

def compare_dates(date, range):

    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    range[0] = datetime.datetime.strptime(range[0], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    range[1] = datetime.datetime.strptime(range[1], '%d/%m/%Y').date()

        if range[0]<=date<=range[1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False


compare_dates('1/1/2017',['1/1/2017','15/12/2017'])   # True
compare_dates('31/12/2015',['1/1/2017','15/12/2017']) # False
compare_dates('1/1/2016',['1/1/2017','15/12/2017'])   # False
```

or even easier, if you just need to filter by year:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('1/1/2017', '%d/%m/%Y').date()
date.year # 2017

date = datetime.datetime.strptime('14/5/2016', '%d/%m/%Y').date()
date.year # 2016
```